# Salvaging Mail in the Exchange "Badmail" folder?

Tags: exchange

A firewall was put up between our SMTP relay and our Exchange server, causing many emails to end up in the "badmail" folder.

However, these are not the actual emails, they are structured like:

```
...

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.
Delivery to the following recipients failed.

...
```

You know what I mean?  The original emails, from what I can tell are nowhere to be found.

A) Is it possible I am not looking in the right place?

B) If these are all I have, the original emails do appear to be on the bottom of these, has anyone ever parsed out the original emails and somehow sent them in an automated way?

Answer (score 1):

> You know what I mean?

No, it's not really clear what you're asking about.  It really sounds to me like you're talking about outgoing messages, but the Badmail folder (which only applies to Exchange versions before 2003 SP1) is where *incoming* messages that can't be delivered and can't be returned to the sender end up.

So before spending too much time on processing Badmail, you should figure out what your firewall is doing to mangle the messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- I am talking about *outgoing* messages.  The firewall situation is all worked out and everything is functioning right now.  However, everything that was sent out during that period of downtime never made it to the recipients.  The only trace of those messages are these bounced messages that ended up in the Badmail folder (they are from postmaster@<servername>.<domain>).  Nothing in the maildrop folder or any of the other folders under inetpub/mailroot